# What should I do if I have a scroll effect on a page and the user either zooms out or has a large resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, scroll

I include scroll effects in a lot of my webpages.For example I would do:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 400){
    $(".SOME_DIV").fadeIn(300);
  }
});
```

This works fine on my screen, but what about others? Different people have different screen sizes, and some people zoom out, so scroll events trigger differently or trigger at all. Is there a different way to create scroll events, or should I just not use them like that?

Comment: Not much you can do unless you work with Percentages, i.e. Take the Screen Size and calculate 10% and after 10% fadeIn the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this plugin called Skrollr:

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

You can set it to work so events are triggered when certain elements are reached when scrolled to, and it's very flexible. For example, you can fade a div in when it is in the center of the page, or 200px from the center of the page, or when it reaches the top of the page, or when it is 147px from the top of the page...you get the idea.